# Solving an equation in R with given constraints

Tags: r, constraints, equation

I want to maximize the following function subject to the given constraints.

> -p<sub>1</sub>log(p<sub>1</sub>) - p<sub>3</sub>log(p<sub>3</sub>) - p<sub>5</sub>log(p<sub>5</sub>)

subject to p<sub>1</sub> + p<sub>3</sub> + p<sub>5</sub> = 1
and p<sub>1</sub> + 3p<sub>3</sub> + 5p<sub>5</sub> = 3.5

p<sub>1</sub> , p<sub>3</sub> and p<sub>5</sub> all lie between 0 and 1 [They are probabilities].

My question is how do I solve this in R? From what I saw, constrOptim() is one of the functions commonly used to solve these type of problems. However I could not figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll get further (more dialog/help) if you include your first attempts with that function.

Comment: @r2evans My function is defined as - 
```f <- function(p1,p2,p3){  return(-p1*log(p1)-p3*log(p3)-p5*log(p5)}```
I am not understanding the other arguments that are needed for the constrOptim() function. For instance, in the RDocumentation, it says that
theta is a numeric (vector) starting value (of length \(p\)): must be in the feasible region.
What is theta in my case?

Comment: constrOptim requires inequality constraints, not equality constraints.  You can find a relevant function/package at https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package `Rsolnp` uses Lagrange multipliers to solve non-linear problems with equality constraints. Here is how it would be setup. `eps` is meant not to have the logarithms produce `NaN` values.

```
library(Rsolnp)

f <-function(X) {
  x <- X[1]
  y <- X[2]
  z <- X[3]
  res <- -x*log(x) - y*log(y) - z*log(z)
  -res
}
eq_f <- function(X){
  x <- X[1]
  y <- X[2]
  z <- X[3]
  c(
    x + y + z,
    x + 3*y + 5*z
  )
}

eps <- .Machine$double.eps*10^2
X0 <- c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)

sol <- solnp(
  pars = X0,
  fun = f,
  eqfun = eq_f,
  eqB = c(1, 3.5),
  LB = rep(eps, 3),
  UB = rep(1, 3)
)
#
#Iter: 1 fn: -1.0512     Pars:  0.21624 0.31752 0.46624
#Iter: 2 fn: -1.0512     Pars:  0.21624 0.31752 0.46624
#solnp--> Completed in 2 iterations

sol$convergence
#[1] 0
sol$pars
#[1] 0.2162396 0.3175208 0.4662396
sol$values
#[1]  0.000000 -1.051173 -1.051173
```

The last value of `sol$values` is the function value at the optimal parameters.
We can check that the constraints are met.

```
sum(sol$pars)
#[1] 1
sum(sol$pars*c(1, 3, 5))
#[1] 3.5
```